# Binding List of object to StimulSoft web report

Tags: c#, stimulsoft

May I know if its possible to bind list of objects, to stimulsoft web?
I'm trying to bind it with regbusinessobject but I have no chance to fetch the expected data. there is always a blank Business Objects in the designer

my code is:

```
StiReport report = new StiReport();
DBEntities entity = new DBEntities();
List<Section> result = entity.Sections.ToList();
report.RegBusinessObject("Section",result);
StiWebDesigner1.Report=report;
stiWebDesigner1.Desighn();
```

Comment: How do you know that it's blank?

Answer (score 2):

in Web you can create a description of the business objects first, then the report template, and then connect the data source with the real data and render a report. Create a description of the business object. 
Notics! : you have to make the class of the business object that is identical to the class of business object in .NET

```
DBEntities entity = new DBEntities();
List<Section> result = entity.Sections.ToList();

StiReport report = new StiReport();
report.RegBusinessObject("Section",result);

int busobjLevel = 1;
report.Dictionary.SynchronizeBusinessObjects(busobjLevel);

//in web you should call design with parameter like this
StiWebDesigner1.Design(report);
```

for showing report  :
Once a report template is created, you can save it, for example to the following path D:\myReport.mrt. Since the description of the business object does not contain the actual data, in order to build a report, you should get the real data to business objects

```
int busobjLevel = 1; 

StiReport report = new StiReport();

report.Load("D:\\myReport.mrt"); 

using (DBEntitiescontext = new DBEntities())

{

var result = entity.Sections.ToList();

report.RegBusinessObject("Sections", result);

StiWebViewer1.Report = report;

}
```